# Need to exclude TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 ssl ciphers postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, ssl, encryption, nmap, sqlcipher

Currently my ssl_ciphers string looks like this:

`ssl_ciphers='ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!3DES:!RC4:!SSLV2:@STRENGTH'`

I want to exclude TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 ciphers along with following ones:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA
```

I was able to exclude TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 ciphers using below

`ssl_ciphers='ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!3DES:!RC4:!SSLV2:!TLSv1.0:!TLSv1.1:@STRENGTH'`

**Edit:** Above change(adding !TLSv1.0:!TLSv1.1) did not exclude TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 ciphers as I can still see them in nmap results.

Is there any way to exclude TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 from ssl_ciphers?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. But instead of finding energy to find those kind of workarounds that will be fragile and break later, just make sure to use TLS 1.3 and nothing else, and that solves your ciphers problem as well as there is nothing to configure on that front when in 1.3

Comment: okay, now I'm just trying to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in general. The issue I'm observing is I can still see them in nmap results after above changes I've stated in original question.

Comment: Excluding some ciphers used by TLS 1.0/1.1 is not the same as completely removing TLS 1.0/1.1 support...

Comment: hmm.. Is there any way I can completely remove TLS 1.0/1.1 support?